# Failing the dependencies check

Tags: magento2, dependency, tests

I'm running the static tests for one of my magento 2 modules `php bin/magento dev:tests:run static` and I get the following errors.

```
Data set: [ROOT]/app/code/Sample/News/Block/Adminhtml/Author/Edit/Buttons/Generic.php
Module Sample\News has undeclared dependencies: hard [Magento\Backend]
[ROOT]/dev/tests/static/testsuite/Magento/Test/Integrity/DependencyTest.php:313
[ROOT]/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Utility/AggregateInvoker.php:56
[ROOT]/dev/tests/static/testsuite/Magento/Test/Integrity/DependencyTest.php:316
```

and others like that.
My `module.xml` file looks like this:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Sample_News" setup_version="2.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Backend"/>
            <module name="Magento_Ui" />
            <module name="Magento_Store" />
            <module name="Magento_Theme" />
            <module name="Magento_Cms" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

my `composer.json` file looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "tzyganu/magento2-sample-module",
  "description": "Magento 2 Sample crud module",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "require": {
    "magento/module-backend": "~100.0.0",
    "magento/module-cms": "~100.0.0",
    "magento/module-ui": "~100.0.0",
    "magento/module-store": "100.0.*",
    "magento/framework": "100.0.*",
    "magento/module-media-storage": "100.0.*",
    "magento/module-directory": "100.0.*"
  },
  "type": "magento2-module",
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "git",
      "url": "https://github.com/tzyganu/Magento2SampleModule"
    }
  ],
  "autoload": {
    "files": [
      "registration.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
      "Sample\\News\\": ""
    }
  }
}
```

Is there an other place where I should declare these dependencies?

**[EDIT]**
While debigging I found out that the module name that [is used here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/dev/tests/static/testsuite/Magento/Test/Integrity/DependencyTest.php#L381) to check for dependencies is `Sample\News` but in the dependency `$_mapDependencies` static var in the same class the module appears as `sample/sample-news`. This means that even if I add all the dependencies correctly it will still say that there is no declared dependency because of this.

Comment: If your code is in /app/code/Sample it's likely not installed via composer. Also where exactly is your composer.json for the module placed?

Comment: it is inside my module `Sample/News/composer.json`. And of course it's not installed via composer. I haven't finished it yet in order to publish it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the edit of the question, this happens because the module name listed in the `composer.json` file does not start with `magento/module-` or `magento/magento`.
The dependency tested converts the module name listed in the composer file but only takes into account the 2 prefixes I mentioned above.
The rest of the module names are not converted so they end up using the name declared in the composer file.
But when checking for dependencies, the dependency test class uses the real module name (`Namespace_Module` or `Namespace\Module`) and it does not find any declared dependencies for it. So it treats any dependency as a hard undeclared one.
I already reported [the issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7421) to the core team

Answer (score 1):

The test verifies the declaration of dependencies in `composer.json`.

But looks like you copy/pasted the module name in composer file. You should name your module like `"sample/module-news"`, and not `"tzyganu/magento2-sample-module"`

Comment: I did that, and I still get the same errors

Comment: Without debugging of test with your module I cannot guess what the problem do you have

Comment: I know. I guess I have to dig in the dependency checker code. Thanks for trying.